# Can A Sweepstakes Promotion Not Have A Winner?

Tags: united-states, sweepstakes

There is already a similar question on this platform and it covers
"Running any game of chance with no intent of showing or awarding winner has legal consequences called fraud, at very least. It's in the law for each state."
But can I run a game of chance with the intent of showing and awarding a winner, where there is still a possibility that no one wins?

Let's say I was running a promotion and I marketed that each entry has an estimated odds of 1 in 5000. When you enter into the promotion, you receive a ticket with a number between 1 and 5000. When it comes tome to choose who won the promotion, a random number between 1 and 5000 is generated and whoever has a ticket that matches the generated number wins the promotion. Now let's say that 5000 entries were not submitted to that promotion and the random number that was generated does not correspond to a ticket that had been purchased. In that case, no one would have won that promotion.

If I were transparent about that being the method used to choose winners, would it be legal? or do I have to ensure that there is always a winner of the promotion (e.g. choosing only out of the tickets that were entered)? And is it legal to enter into your own promotion (e.g. you fill what falls short of 5000 entries with your own entries)?

Comment: How do you know that a ticket hasn't been allocated?  Because if you do know, you can just keep running your random number generator until you match a ticket that has been allocated to someone.  And this should have been published as a part of the rules of the sweepstakes.

Comment: Ticket entries are logged, I can generate a random number that will 100% guarantee a winner, but do I legally have to?

Comment: By "do I legally have to", do you mean you "have no intention of picking a winner (and are doing a runner with the money)"?, or do you mean you "will only make 1 attempt to pick a winner, and if there is no winner, the money will be rolled over into the next sweepstakes event"?  Because the former is fraud, while the latter is how every major lottery in the US works.

Comment: I mean that I will only make 1 attempt to pick a winner, and if there is no winner, the prize just won't be paid out to anyone.

Comment: Did the ticket holders have to exchange anything in order to receive a ticket?  And where did the prize come from?

Comment: There are alternate methods of entry, but purchasing a ticket is one way of entering into the promotion. The prize money comes from the host of the sweepstakes promotion holder. In the case of no winner being chosen, that money (including ticket profits) would be given host of the promotion. (assuming I'm allowed to run it like that)

Comment: I wonder if there would need to be consideration. So maybe lottery tickets no, no purchase necessary sweepstakes no, sweepstakes enter with purchase yes?

Answer (score -2):

A sweepstakes without a winner would be fraud.  **A sweepstakes is defined as there being a prize.**

1 in 5000 odds is an estimated chance of winning, it means you expect 5000 entries.  Deciding to not pay out because you have "extra" numbers you can select is unethical and almost certainly illegal.  In the US, sweepstakes like this are regulated by states, and the one you're in would be unimpressed with your scheme.  In my state, sweepstakes are covered by specific laws, upheld by regulation by the state Attorney General.

I want to back up and clarify terms.  A sweepstakes is a thing where if people enter, then a sweepstakes winner is selected from those who entered.   This might be a "game of chance" but **someone must always win**.  Doing something else (like a Lotto or scratch-off game) is gambling and will be legislated and regulated on a much tighter basis.  If it is a sweepstakes, someone has to win, and that someone cannot be the operator.

Schemes like this have almost certainly been tried before and have been regulated out because people don't like being scammed.

Comment: So if the ticket number 500 were picked and no one had a corresponding ticket number, not paying out would be illegal? Assuming so, would it be illegal to fill in the missing entries with your own entries? Say only 4500 people entered into your promotion, could you enter your own promotion 500 times?

Comment: Re: buy your own tickets.  Is the prize fixed (an ipad, a fixed dollar amount) or does it go up with more tickets sold (the prize is the pot of money or a percentage of same)?

Comment: @DanielVerfurth, in a sweepstakes you can't pick ticket 500 unless someone had it.  If only 4500 people entered, their chances to win would now be 1 in 4500.

Comment: The prize is fixed, defined at the creation of the promotion.